# Unable to assign output of FactoryGirl.create(:user) to a :user variable when factory uses 'sequence'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, factory-bot

I'm following Michael Hartl's great book on Ruby on Rails(rails 3.2 version). I'm having some problems in section **9.3.3. Pagination**.

After I modified my factory at `spec/factories.rb` using `sequence` like this(note that I have the previous version commented out):

```rb
FactoryGirl.define do
    #factory :user do
    #   name "Michael Hartl"
    #   email "michael@example.com"
    #   password "foobar"
    #   password_confirmation "foobar"
    #end
    factory :user do
        sequence(:user){ |n| "Person #{n}" }
        sequence(:email){ |n| "person_#{n}@example.com"}
        password "foobar"
        password_confirmation "foobar"
    end
end
```

I cannot use this anymore in my tests:

```rb
let(:user){ FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
```

For instance the test with code:

```rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

    subject { page }
    describe "index" do

        let(:user){ FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

        before(:all){ 30.times {FactoryGirl.create(:user) }}
        after(:all) {User.delete_all}

        before(:each) do
            valid_signin user
            visit users_path
        end

        it { should have_selector('title', text: 'All users') }
        it { should have_selector('h1',  text: 'All users') }

.
.
.
end
```

Returns errors such as:

```rb
Failure/Error: before(:all){ 30.times {FactoryGirl.create(:user) }}
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `user=' for #<User:0x00000002760140>
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:16:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:16:in `times'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

It somehow makes sense that I can't use this syntax (`let(:user){...}`) anymore, since I'm now creating sequences of elements, but I can't seem to find a fix for this.

Any ideas? thanks!

Comment: I believe it should be `sequence(:name)`, not `sequence(:user)`.

Comment: damnit! so obvious, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean `sequence(:name)` instead of `sequence(:user)` in your factory. It's looking for a method `user=` in your `User` model instead of the `name=` method.